# Unable to upload image in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am working on laravel 5.3.30 and using image intervention helper for uploading image. I am getting error "NotWritableException in Image.php line 143: Can't write image data to path (/home/test/Desktop/Laravel/blog/public/images/)" while uploading image. I have set appropriate permission to the directory but still am not able to upload image.

Code to upload image file:

```
if($request->hasFile('featured_image')){
            $image = $request->file('featured_image');
            $filename = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('images/', $filename);
            Image::make($image)->resize(800,400)->save($location);
            $post->image = $filename;
        }
```

I have checked the solutions online but none it worked. Please correct me if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error: NotWritableException in Image.php line 143: Can't write image data to path (/home/test/Desktop/Laravel/blog/public/images/)" while uploading image

Comment: Just to confirm, the `images` directory already exists, right?

Comment: @camelCase - yes, it is already there

Comment: Sorry guyz, I know this is embarrassing. I apologize for your wasting time. I made mistake in my code. I accidentally put ',' instead of '.'

Comment: No worries, it happens! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Here is alternative approach. Consider storing in `storage` directory, not in `public`. This is [Laravel recommended way](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#configuration).

It may be storing inside `storage/app/public/images` directory. And then create symlink with `php artisan storage:link` command.

This way when storing use this path:

```
$location = storage_path('app/images/', $filename);
```

After symlink is created, you may access image url like 
    `http://your-site.app/storage/images/qwerqrewqerwq.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to fix permissions:

```
chmod -R 755 /home/Desktop/Laravel/blog/public
```

If it'll not work and if it's a local machine, try 777.

Comment: Yes it is localmachine and tried this too but it didn't work.

command line: chmod -R 777 /home/test/Desktop/Laravel/blog/public